# How to use email variables in post session success command

Tags: informatica

I am unable to fetch the email variables which contain session run properties (like %w,%s) in post session success command value.

Comment: Give more information to understand. Is email task finished successfully? Do you get %w instead of actual workflow name or do you get error while using the variables?

Comment: Email variables are not supposed to work in post session command. Try using the built-in mapping variables `$PMWorkflowName` and `$PMSessionName`

Comment: @Samik thats ok.But then how to get the Target Success rows and other variables in post succession command.I don't want to make user defined variables and copy in them using link.Please suggest if there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

EMAIL SUBJECT:  Session failure notification

EMAIL:  The session %s  in the workflow %w  failed. Please find attached the session log for more details. %g

echo session_name,folder_name(if required),@TableName,@numAffectedRows,%DATE% %TIME% >$PMRootDir\file_name.txt

Try this in email-failure Notifications